# Disable plugins for specific CKEditor

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

How can I disable plugins for a specific CKEditor? I have a CKeditor where you make a post and another one for commenting on that post. What I want help with is to disable plugins on the editor of comments.

For example:

Comment editor has id `CKEditor_30` is there a way to disable plugins for only this editor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

All I had to do was to create a custom config file `custom_config.js` and copied contents from `config.js`.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {

    config.mathJaxLib = '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';
    config.extraPlugins = 'lineutils,mathjax,widget';
    config.toolbar = [
       ['Styles'],['Bold','Italic','Underline'],
       ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
       ['Image','Table','-','Link','Flash','Smiley','TextColor','BGColor']
    ];
};
```

After that I linked editors to that config file:

```
<textarea name="new_comment" id="CKEditor_<?=$getpost['post_id']?>" placeholder="Write something ..."></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditor_<?=$getpost['post_id']?>',{
         customConfig : '/website/ckeditor/custom_config.js',
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.